# Max worker =4 doesn't work for my python discord bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

There is a max worker problem with my discord bot that causes it to stop running and throws me a long error message.

I've got a file called main.py. Along with a folder called cogs. Inside cogs, there are two files: admin and member. Inside the admin file are commands that only admins can use. While inside the member file are commands that everyone can use. In main.py, I've got this code:

```
#discord imports
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

#module imports
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
from dotenv import load_dotenv

#token
token = "secret"

#intents and bot
load_dotenv() 
intents = discord.Intents.all()
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="?", intents=intents)
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4)

cogs = ["admin", "member"]
for cog in cogs:
  try:
    bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog.lower()}')
    print(f'{cog} cog loaded.')
  except Exception as e:
    print(f'Failed to load {cog} cog: {e}')

#login event
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=f"?help"))
  await asyncio.sleep(1)
  print("\n Bot has successfully logged in as: {}".format(bot.user))
  print("Bot ID: {}\n".format(bot.user.id))

#run the bot
try:
  bot.run(token)
except discord.HTTPException as e:
  if e.status == 429:
    print("The Discord servers denied the connection for making too many requests")
  else:
    raise e
```

When I run the code, it throws this error at me:

```
main.py:22: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BotBase.load_extension' was never awaited
  bot.load_extension(f'cogs.{cog.lower()}')
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
admin cog loaded.
member cog loaded.
2023-06-11 13:21:15 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 37, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 860, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 849, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 777, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 612, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 624, in request
    async with self.__session.request(method, url, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 520, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 535, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 892, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 999, in _create_direct_connection
    hosts = await asyncio.shield(host_resolved)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 865, in _resolve_host
    addrs = await self._resolver.resolve(host, port, family=self._family)
  File "/home/runner/Discord-Bot/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/aiohttp/resolver.py", line 31, in resolve
    infos = await self._loop.getaddrinfo(
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 825, in getaddrinfo
    return await self.run_in_executor(
  File "/nix/store/p21fdyxqb3yqflpim7g8s1mymgpnqiv7-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 780, in run_in_executor
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_workers'
```

What is the problem. And how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `ThreadPoolExecutor()` in your code, so maybe you could just remove it.

```
import concurrent.futures
executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)
```

Comment: Actually the `max_workers` don't have to be specified since 3.5: https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/concurrent.futures.html?highlight=threadpoolexecutor#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: You right, I modified my answer

Comment: it gives this to me: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_workers'`

Comment: lets specify the max_worker, I modified my answer

Comment: it still says: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'max_workers'`

Comment: This error doesnt seem to come from a code you have shown